# I need help in using populartime as Django REST API to use in ionic

Tags: python, django, ionic-framework, django-rest-framework

I'm new in Python & Django and I need to use Populartime repo https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes as API to work with in my ionic application put I didn't found the way yet?
I tried to create Django $project and create $app put how to include Populartime and use it as API

this is the project i have create and i tried to use the Populartime as a module put didn't no how to use it later:
[image: this is the project i have create and i tried to use the Populartime as a module put didn't no how to use it later]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your code as a [formatted code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) instead of an image link.

Comment: In addition, please consider making it a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and including information about what you have tried and what errors you get.

Comment: Inline image; trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization; grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do it like this:

`import populartimes`

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for help ,,**

The answer is simple put i was don't know how to work with python.

```
from populartimes import get_id
```

Or any other function instude of (get_id).